# Need to recommend mobile app store link from web site when using mobile

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net-mvc, mobile

My web site has a Mobile app in AppStore and PlayStore. I need to recommend app link to users when using mobile device and web site. 
If the app is already installed on the mobile, no need to show the appstore link on the web.

Is it possible to detect app installed from web site?

Is there any available meta tag related to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can add a smart banner in your website for iOS applications. Here is the link to the official documentation: [iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html)

For android there is no such official implementation till now as far i know. But here is the link of a custom [jQuery Smart Banner](http://www.jasny.net/jquery.smartbanner/#android) which can be used for iOS,Android and Windows Store apps too.

Another way that you can use intent filter in your main-app activity so when the desired url is called then the main activity will start.

```
<intent-filter>
    <data
        android:host="www.xyz.com"
        android:pathPrefix="/mobileapps"
        android:scheme="http" >
    </data>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions, Yes!

For the Appstore, Apple have documented it here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html

And for the meta tag it looks something like this:

```
<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=myURL">
```